# blf + bgl text flickering

Tags: python, 3d-view, operator

I'm using `blf` in a modal operator to draw help text on the 3D viewport. Here's a snippet:

```
FONT_ID = 0
bgl.glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
try:
    blf.position(FONT_ID, x, y, 0)
    blf.draw(FONT_ID, line)
finally:
    bgl.glColor4f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

This works well, but when the user moves the mouse, the text flickers: when the mouse is moving it's a bit bigger, and when it stops it goes smaller. When it's bigger it also appears a little blurry. I think the texture that the text is being painted onto is being scaled incorrectly when the mouse moves. I've checked the parameters that I'm passing to `blf.draw` and `blf.position`, and they're not changing.

Is there any way I can stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

Oops, I should have been setting the font size.

```
blf.size(FONT_ID, 14, 72)
```

My guess is that some other text code is not resetting the font size properly. Similarly, when using text shadow, you have to set the `blf.shadow_offset` (even if you want to leave it at `0, 0`) to avoid the shadow flickering.